# Add resource to Xamarin.Forms NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm about to write a custom NuGet for Xamarin.Forms projects and want to include some resources (font awesome otfs) in the NuGet so the referencing projects can use them.

I've managed it to copy the files from the NuGet to the Android assets folder and mark them as assets file correctly.
However I'm not able to include them in iOS as resource files...

Did anyone know how to do that? Or how to include resources at all (with a NuGet).

Here is my code snippet from the csproj file (NuGet) that works for android but not for iOS:

```xml
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- If config is release create a package -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Release' ">
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>

    <!-- sourcelink: Include PDB in the built .nupkg -->
    <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="fonts" />
    <FontFiles Include="fonts\*.otf" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="@(FontFiles)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('xamarin.ios')) ">
    <Compile Include="ios\**\*.ios.cs" />
    <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="@(FontFiles)" BuildAction="BundleResource" PackagePath="contentFiles\any\$(TargetFramework)\Resources\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('monoandroid')) ">
    <Compile Include="android\**\*.android.cs" />
    <Folder Include="Assets\" />
    <AndroidAsset Include="@(FontFiles)" Link="Assets\%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: There is one article about create nuget and include in project, you can take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work... Because the font files should be marked as BundleResource to be recognized under ios... and the compiler does not copy the files when using the <file> node

Comment: I search some info, but still having some ways to do, so can you consider to use custom Fonts directly? This is the article:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/custom-fonts-in-ios/